# bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/usr/local/bin/fastlane) in ubuntu when run in GitHub Actions

Tags: ruby

I am using this command to install fastlane in GitHub Actions in Ubuntu image:

```
  - name: Bundle install
    run: |
      cd ./android
      curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
      curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg --import -
      echo 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3:6: | gpg --import-ownertrust
      echo 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB:6: | gpg --import-ownertrust
      curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --ignore-dotfiles
      source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
      source ~/.bash_profile
      rvm --version
      rvm install 2.7.2
      rvm use --default 2.7.2
      gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.0
      gem install fastlane -v 2.177.0
      bundle install
```

but when I using this command like this to build a android apk using fastlane in GitHub Actions on Ubuntu OS:

```
 - name: Deploy to TestFlight/PGY
        run: |
          cd ./android
          bundle exec fastlane android beta
```

shows could not found fastlane command:

```
  cd ./android
  bundle exec fastlane android beta
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    JAVA_HOME_12.0.2_x64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/12.0.2/x64
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/12.0.2/x64
    JAVA_HOME_12_0_2_X64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/12.0.2/x64
    FLUTTER_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/2.0.1-stable/x64
    FLUTTER_ROOT: ***
    APPLE_ID: ***
    GIT_URL: ***
    PGY_USER_KEY: ***
    PGY_API_KEY: ***
    TEAM_ID: ***
    ITC_TEAM_ID: ***
    FASTLANE_USER: 
    FASTLANE_PASSWORD: ***
    FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: 
    FASTLANE_SESSION: 
    MATCH_PASSWORD: ***
    MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME: ***
    MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ***
    DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS: 
bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/usr/local/bin/fastlane)
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:89:in `block in materialize': Could not find aws-sdk-s3-1.93.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `map!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `materialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/definition.rb:255:in `specs_for'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `requested_specs'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block in definition_method'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `setup'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:61:in `require_relative'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:61:in `kernel_load'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/cli.rb:494:in `exec'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.14/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

why the fastlane still not found after I am installled?

Comment: Looks like you need to install the AWS Ruby SDK. (`Could not find aws-sdk-s3-1.93.0`.)

Comment: @Dolphin did you managed to fix this? I have the same issue now

Comment: I have fixed it  but I forget how to fix it, I facing this problem long time ago,@Jkrist sorry fot that I could not help you right now.

Comment: If you get this error on MacOS, the answer is to update the bundler: `bundle update`

Comment: @Grizly
Thank you. 
"bundle update" worked for me

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @Grizly if you are experiencing this on macOS, then try running `bundle update`